# How do I keep my SQLite Database organized? Android

Tags: android, sqlite, organization

Say my SQLite Databate has 2 columns, the first being an auto-incrementing ID and the 2nd being some string. Say right now it's

1 random
2 jellybean
3 ImTired

if I were to delete entry 2, it would then be

1 random
3 ImTired

What I want is a way to make it so when you delete entry 2, it turns it into

1 random
2 ImTired

I thought about updating the entries to shift them all down one and delete the last one, but even if it worked(in my case, it deleted all of my entries, but whatever...), and even if I did get it to
1 random
2 ImTired

the next time I create a new entry, it'll be entry 4. I don't think this necessary to my app, but it seriously bugs me.

Comment: I'm not a database expert, but if that auto-incrementing ID is the primary key of your table, then I would suggest that you should leave them as they are. Is it just because it bugs you? If you are using the values as a rowcount or for display, there may be other ways to handle that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ID column on your DB is working as a Primary Key, which is a column or group of columns used to uniquely identify a row. Once you set a Primary Key on a row you shouldn't change it, else you risk losing the consistency of the DB. For instance, suppose you later create another table that references the rows in your first table. That reference will be made using the Primary Key, and if you later change it your data won't make sense anymore.

If you wanted the ID column to keep changing just to reflect the number of rows in your table you can solve that problem with other methods. For instance. SQL offers a COUNT operator that will return the number of rows in your table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table_name;
```